# How to get variable's value from Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

First, im a begiiner in GSON so please bear with me.

I have a set of classes with this structure :

```
class Response
  Data data;

class Data
  List<Item> items;

class Item
  String id;
  String title;
  Private Player;

class Player
  String mobile;
```

Im using those class to retrieve the JSON with GSON library.

I successfully retrieve the JSON data with this code :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response myResponse = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, Response.class);
```

When i debug the code, i can see the `Item` class value is successfully retrieved inside the `myResponse`. However, i have a problem when i want to access the `title` variable in the `Item` Class because all i have is a `Response` Class.

**How to get the `title` variable in the `Item` Class?**

Any help is apprciated, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `public` attributes (which is usually [a bad practice](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html#177)!) you can just do:

```
//This will iterate over all items
for (Item item : myResponse.data.items) {
    //for each item now you can get the title
    String title = myItem.title;
}
```

---

Anyway, as I said, you should make your attributes `private`, and have [getters and setters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) for those attributes. That's Java basics!

Namely, in your `Response` class, you should have something like:

```
private Data data;

public Data getData(){
    return this.data;
}
public void setData(Data data){
    this.data = data;
}
```

In the same way, you should have `private` attributes and getters and setters in all your classes.

So now you can access your items in the proper way with:

```
//Get the Data object with the getter method
Data data = myResponse.getData();
for (Item item : data.getItems()) {
    String title = myItem.getTitle();
}
```

Comment: +1 but I wouldn't add setters unless they were necessary, GSON doesn't require them.

Comment: @Jonathan: you may be right, I'm not an expert. But I usually do exactly the opposite: I wouldn't have public attributes *unless they were necessary* ;) Maybe it's just an habit...

Comment: @MikO Again, thanks a lot for your help :D Its too bad i only can upvote once.

Comment: @MikO err...i have a funny question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028616/how-to-read-json-variable-that-use-number-for-its-name-with-gson Sorry its my first time playing with GSON :D

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the data like this:-

```
Data myData = myResponse.getData();
for(Item myItem : myData.getItems()){
    // myItem.getTitle(); will give you the title from each Item
}
```

This is assuming that you've getters for all the fields in the classes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get the logic but i get confuse how to implement it. What should the getData method in Response class have?

My current Response Class only have this code : public Data data;
 
 public Response() {
  data = new Data();
 }

Comment: `public Data getData(){return this.data;}` - This is what your `getData` method should look like!