# How to read JSON variable that use number for its name, with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

First, im a beginner in GSON so please bear with me.

I tried to read a JSON from this url :

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=radityadika&v=2&alt=jsonc`

I succeed to read a String variable like "id", "data", "uploader", etc.

However, how can i read the `content` (inside `items`)? I want to get the RTSP link (`content:1`) but my Java keep give me error because i cant name a variable with number, like :

```
String 1 = "asd";
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks for your help

Comment: can you post your JSON here ?

Comment: You can create `Map<Integer,String>` or `Map<String,String>`, posted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need define several classes first of all:

**MyGson**

```
public class MyGson {
private String apiVersion;
private Data data;

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}
}
```

**Data**

```
public class Data {
private String updated;
private int totalItems = 0;
private int startIndex = 0;
private int itemsPerPage = 0;
private  List<Item> items;

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}
}
```

**Item**

```
 public class Item {
private String id;
private String uploaded;
private String updated;
private String uploader;
private String category;
private String title;
private String description;
private Map<Integer, String>  content;

public Map<Integer, String> getContent() {
    return content;
}
}
```

Take a look, your `content` is map where `key` is 1,2,3,4,5,6 ....

You can define `Map<String, String> content` but since all your keys are integers..

So now you can extract any value you want:

**Launcher**

```
 ....
 Gson gson = new Gson();

    MyGson myGson = gson.fromJson(str, MyGson.class);

    List<Item> items = myGson.getData().getItems();

    if(items.size()>0){
        Item item = items.get(0);

        String myStr = item.getContent().get(1);

        System.out.println(myStr);
    }
```

Output:

```
rtsp://r6---sn-cg07lue6.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQl1cubZZSUSXxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

Answer (score 7):

It's old but maybe someone needs it still...

To serialize properties which name is just Integer just make model class like:

Json:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "1": "value one",
  "2": "value two",
  "3": "value three"
}
```

Java:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Foo {

   private String name;

   @SerializedName("1")
   private String one;

   @SerializedName("2")
   private String two;

   @SerializedName("3")
   private String three;

   // standard getter & setters bellow...

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking into account that the `content` JSON object looks like this:

```
"content": {
    "1": "someLink",
    "5": "someOtherLink",
    ...
}
```

The best way to parse that JSON object is as a `Map` (see [Map documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)), so you just need to add an attribute to your `Item` class like this:

```
private Map<Integer, String> content;
```

Basically a Map is an object containing pairs of `key - value`, in your case the keys are `Integer` and the values are `String`.

So then you can access your link looking for the key of the value you want to retrieve, in the case of the first link, it's just:

```
String someLink = content.get(new Integer(1));
```

Note that doing it this way you can have different numbers for the links. Now you have 1, 5 and 6. But you could have any integers and an arbitrary number of links...

Answer (score 1):

Java languge does not allow variable naming like this.

A relevant exceprt is quoted herein, please see the link below for details,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

> Every programming language has its own set of rules and conventions
> for the kinds of names that you're allowed to use, and the Java
> programming language is no different. The rules and conventions for
> naming your variables can be summarized as follows:
>
> 1. Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>    digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>    underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin
>    your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the
>    dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>    find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>    dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>    similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>    technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
>    practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.
> 2. Subsequent characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or underscore characters. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this
>    rule as well. When choosing a name for your variables, use full words
>    instead of cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier
>    to read and understand. In many cases it will also make your code
>    self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example,
>    are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and
>    g. Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or
>    reserved word.
> 3. If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell that word in all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one word,
>    capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. The names
>    gearRatio and currentGear are prime examples of this convention. If
>    your variable stores a constant value, such as static final int
>    NUM_GEARS = 6, the convention changes slightly, capitalizing every
>    letter and separating subsequent words with the underscore character.
>    By convention, the underscore character is never used elsewhere.