# LibGDX JSON parsing from an API

Tags: android, json, libgdx

I'm trying to parse a JSON returned by OpenWeatherMap API, specifically [this](http://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON).

I'm using the approach suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401431/libgdx-json-parsing), that is create classes with class variables with names same as parameters in the returned JSON. It works for all parameters except the "3h" one in "rain" and "snow".

Obviously, I can't create a variable named 3h in Java and the class variable has to have the same name.

Is there a way how to parse it all (including the "3h") properly?

Comment: Why does class variable have to have the same name? What class / tool do you use to deserialize the JSON? Post some code.

Comment: @Ascorbin I couldn't post more than two links, I'm sorry. I'm using LibGDX so it's this - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON

The class in which I wrap the info is in the original post.

Comment: Use a map? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028616/how-to-read-json-variable-that-use-number-for-its-name-with-gson

Comment: @noumenal Yes, that's possible too. LibGDX does it like [this](http://jackyjjc.com/2013/10/07/parsing-json-in-libgdx-tutorial/) (at the very end). I'm willing to do it that way if there's no simpler alternative.

Comment: Have you tried social engineering? Maybe you could suggest that they change the API to be compatible with Java (e.g. https://openweathermap.desk.com)

Comment: You would probably need to use another library like `GSON`, or use event-based parsing on your own.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes, looks like I'll have to parse it myself.

Comment: @8311697110108101122 Please provide your solution as an "Answer" below and mark the question accepted.  Its more likely to show up usefully to future users that way.  Plus you get some rep.  Thanks.

Comment: @P.T. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there were few solutions:

- Use an ObjectMap ([link](http://jackyjjc.com/2013/10/07/parsing-json-in-libgdx-tutorial/), at the very end)
- Parse it myself (the last resort)
- or the one I'm currently employing successfully:

  ```
  /*...*/
  Json json = new Json();
  String jsonStr = /* JSON here */
  jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("\"3h\"", "\"_3h\"");
  JSONWrapper jsonWrapper = json.fromJson(JSONWrapper.class, jsonStr);
  /*...*/
  ```

Accessing values:

```
double windSpeed = jsonWrapper.wind.speed;
```

And the wrapper class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JSONWrapper {
    Coord coord;
    ArrayList<Weather> weather;
    String base;
    MainJ main;
    Wind wind;
    Clouds clouds;
    Rain rain;
    Snow snow;
    int dt;
    Sys sys;
    int id;
    String name;
    int cod;
    String message;
    Visibility visibility;
}

class Weather {
    int id;
    String main;
    String description;
    String icon;
}

class Coord {
    double lon;
    double lat;
}

class Visibility {
    String value;
}

class MainJ {
    double temp;
    int pressure;
    int humidity;
    double temp_min;
    double temp_max;
}

class Wind {
    double speed;
    int deg;
}

class Clouds {
    int all;
}

class Snow {
    int _3h;
}

class Rain {
    int _3h;
}

class Sys {
    int type;
    int id;
    double message;
    String country;
    int sunrise;
    int sunset;
}
```